# Python Class replacement not working

Tags: python-3.x

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: [str]):
        self._foo = a
        self._bar = b

    def get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    def get_bar(self):
        return self._bar

def do_that(given):
    x = given.get_foo()
    x += 10

    y = given.get_bar()
    y[0] += ' there'
    y = ['cool']

    given = A(-10, ['test'])

x = A(1, ['hello'])
print(x.get_bar())
```

How come print(x.get_bar()) prints hello there, instead of 'test' when given is replaced with A(-10, ['test'])? In a similar function like this,

```
def test(x):
    x = 4
    return x

x = 1
test(x)
```

x is replaced with 4 and 4 is actually returned.

Comment: try to `print(x)` at the end of your last example

Answer (score 0):

In your second bit of code `def test(x):`, you're overwriting the input to 4, regardless of what you put in by setting `x = 4`.

In your first bit of code, you're not actually calling the `do_that(given):` function when you call `x.get_bar()`, so the `['hello']` will not be overwritten with `['test']`. Also, where `given` is defined as a variable within `def get_bar(given):`, it is not ever being used.